# How to prettify a JSON String in Flex / Actionscript?

Tags: json, actionscript-3, apache-flex

As a result of a HTTP request I've got JSON data in the URLLoader object. I need to put the JSON in a formatted way inside a TextField.

How can I accomplish that this:

```
[{"id":"barrrrrr","client":"foo"}]
```

looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "id":"barrrrrr",
      "client":"foo"
   }
]
```

inside the textfield?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the native JSON object in flash player 11+

```
var stringJSON:String = loader.data as String;
var jsonData:Object = JSON.parse(stringJSON);
textField.text = JSON.stringify(jsonData,null,4);
```

Comment: With that I've got `"{\"id\":\"barrrrr\",\"client\":\"foo\")"`

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly the same what you asked, but we use this method for logging as3 object (json as well), may be it will be useful for you too:

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;

public class astest extends Sprite
{
    public function astest()
    {
        var jsonStr:String = '[{"id":"barrrrrr","client":{"id":"barrrrrr","client":"foo"}},{"id":"barrrrrr","client":"foo"}]';
        var jsonObj:Object = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

        trace(parse(jsonObj));
    }

    private static const simpleTypes:Array = ["int", "uint", "String", "Number", "Boolean", "null", "XML", "void"];
    private static function parse(o:Object, tabs:String = ""):String
    {
        var out:String = "";
        var tabStr:String = "    ";
        var cnt:int = 40;           //number of properties on the same object to log out 
        var type:String;

        for(var prop:* in o)
        {
            type = "null";
            try{
                type = getQualifiedClassName(o[prop]);
            }catch(error:Error){};

            out+= tabs + String(prop) + ":" + type + " = ";

            if(simpleTypes.indexOf(type) >=0)
                out+=o[prop]+"\r";
            else
                out+=type+"\r"+parse(o[prop], tabs+tabStr);

            if(--cnt<=0)
            {
                out+=tabs+"...\r";
                break;
            }
        }

        return out;
    }
}
}
```

The output for this example will be:

```
0:Object = Object
    client:Object = Object
        client:String = foo
        id:String = barrrrrr
    id:String = barrrrrr
1:Object = Object
    client:String = foo
    id:String = barrrrrr
```

You can modify *parse* method (it's quite simple) to make output more similar to yours.

Comment: jepp, but with this way I also could count brakets and braces and prettify it myself.